# asp sitemap for a folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitemap

I want to create a sitemap for my application. Is it possible to point a node to a folder so all pages in this folder will have the role set by the node?

```
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >  
<siteMapNode title="Private Pages" roles="Provate" url="">
  <siteMapNode title="Secure folder" url="/MainFolder">
  </siteMapNode>      
</siteMapNode>
```

Thanks to anyone who can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roles for a folder are not set in your sitemap. You should rather create a local `web.config` file in the folder and setup your authorization rules there.

What you CAN do in a sitemap is to have a node visible or invisible to users and all subnodes can inherit the setting.

Note that whether or not a user can SEE a link in your menu is not related to whether or not the user can ACCESS the resource by pointing the browser to resource's url.

That's why you should have both: authorization rules in local configuration files (to prevent users from accessing resources) and sitemap rules (to prevent users from seeing links in the menu).